# Interaction Hamiltonian in the interaction picutre

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian-formalism, notation, interactions

The Schrodinger and Heisenberg pictures make sense to me. But the interaction picture which is a hybrid of the two does not.

Author of this text first splits the Hamiltonian up as

$$H=H_0+H_{int}$$

The time dependence of operators is governed by $H_0$ while the time dependence of states is governed by $H_{int}$.

**(Question, does this say that the Hamiltonian is broken into a time dependent  $H_0$ and a time independent $H_{int}$ parts?)**

The states and operators in the interaction picture is denoted by a subscript $I$:

$$|\psi(t) \rangle_{I}=e^{iH_{0}t}|\psi(t) \rangle_{S}$$

$$\mathcal{O}_{I}(t)=e^{iH_{0}t}\mathcal{O}_{S}e^{-iH_{0}t}$$

The last equation applies to $H_{int}$, which is time dependent

**(Question, is this a typo? should it be time independent?)**

The interaction Hamiltonian in the interaction picture is then

$$(H_{int})_{I}=e^{iH_{0}t}(H_{int})_{S}e^{-iH_{0}t}$$

$$H_{I}=(H_{int})_{I}$$

**(Question, this implies that $(H_0)_I=0{}$, what sense this notation makes? is it that time dependent part of the Hamilotinain in the interaction picture vanishes?  but why)**

This result is used to find the Schrodinger equation for states in the interaction picture

$$i\frac {d|\psi\rangle_{I}}{dt}=H_{I}(t)|\psi\rangle_{I}$$.

**(Question, this also assumes that $(H_0)_{S}=H_0$, what sense this notation makes?)
Perhaps an overall question that relates all confusion to each other. When **we do not use any of the subscripts, we are in which pictures? $S, H, I$?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Author of this text first splits the Hamiltonian up as
>
> $$H=H_0+H_{int}$$
>
> The time dependence of operators is governed by $H_0$ while the time
>   dependence of states is governed by $H_{int}$.
>
> **(Question, does this say that the Hamiltonian is broken into a time dependent  $H_0$ and a time independent $H_{int}$ parts?)**

No, not necessarily, the full Hamiltonian is broken into two parts arbitrarily (i.e., in a way that *you* get to choose).

> The states and operators in the interaction picture is denoted by a
>   subscript $I$:
>
> $$|\psi(t) \rangle_{I}=e^{iH_{0}t}|\psi(t) \rangle_{S}$$
>
> $$\mathcal{O}_{I}(t)=e^{iH_{0}t}\mathcal{O}_{S}e^{-iH_{0}t}$$
>
> The last equation applies to $H_{int}$, which is time dependent
>
> **(Question, is this a typo? should it be time independent?)**

No, not necessarily. It will only be time-independent if it it: 1) Commutes with the unperturbed Hamiltonian; and 2) has no explicit time-dependence. Typically the first condition is not satisfied, so the interaction Hamiltonian in the interaction picture does have time dependence.

> The interaction Hamiltonian in the interaction picture is then
>
> $$(H_{int})_{I}=e^{iH_{0}t}(H_{int})_{S}e^{-iH_{0}t}$$
>
> $$H_{I}=(H_{int})_{I}$$
>
> **(Question, this implies that $(H_0)_I=0{}$,

No, it is not zero. This should say $(H_0)_I=H_0$. Because $H_0$ commutes with $e^{iH_0t}$.

> what sense this notation makes? 
>   is it that time dependent part of the Hamilotinain in the
>   interaction picture vanishes?  but why)**

As explained above, what you wrote above is incorrect.

> This result is used to find the Schrodinger equation for states in the
>   interaction picture
>
> $$i\frac {d|\psi\rangle_{I}}{dt}=H_{I}(t)|\psi\rangle_{I}$$.
>
> **(Question, this also assumes that $(H_0)_{S}=H_0$, what sense this notation makes?)

$(H_0)_H=e^{iAt}H_0e^{-iAt}$, where $A=H$. So, typically $(H_0)_H\neq H_0$ because $H_0$ doesn't typically commute with $H$.

$(H_0)_I=e^{iAt}H_0e^{-iAt}$, where $A=H_0$. So, $(H_0)_I=H_0$ because $H_0$ commutes with itself.

$(H_0)_S=e^{iAt}H_0e^{-iAt}$, where $A=0$. So, $(H_0)_S=H_0$ because $H_0$ commutes with $1$ (i.e., $e^0$).

Comment: Thanks all clear now. Also it seems that this equation is indeed a convention on notation, right? $$H_{I}=(H_{int})_{I}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\lvert #1 \rangle}\newcommand{\timex}[1]{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} #1 t}}\newcommand{\ntimex}[1]{\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} #1 t}}$The interaction picture split of the *Schrödinger* picture Hamiltonian

$$ H_S = H_{0,S} + H_{\text{int}_S} $$

has nothing to do with the Hamiltonians themselves being time (in)dependent. In fact, the choice of $H_{0,S}$ and $H_{\text{int},S}$ as summands of the total Hamiltonian $H_S$ is totally arbitrary, and every choice yields a "different" interaction picture. It is common, however, to choose $H_{0,S}$ as a *free* or *unperturbed* Hamiltonian and $H_{\text{int},S}$ as the terms that contain the interactions or perturbations from a simpler system.

Now, in the interaction picture, a bit confusingly, all the states and operators are time-dependent, in contrast to the Heisenberg and Schrödinger pictures. Starting from the Schrödinger picture with states $\ket{\psi_S(t)}$ and time-independent operators $A_S$, we define

$$ A_I(t) = \timex{H_{0,S}}A_S\ntimex{H_{0,S}}$$

$$ \ket{\psi_I(t)} = \timex{H_{0,S}}\ket{\psi_S(t)}$$

Where the first definition makes it so operators now evolve by $H_0$ and the second "removes" the evolution by $H_0$ from the evolution of the Schrödinger state, leaving the evolution by $H_\text{int}$. The equations of motion reflect that - they are Schrödinger for the states with Hamiltonian $H_\text{int}$ and Heisenberg for the operators with Hamiltoian $H_0$.

Furthermore, $H_{0,I}(t) = H_{0,I}(0) = H_{0,S}$ at all times, since $H_0$ commutes with its own exponential, so we need not distinguish between $H_{0,S}$ and $H_{0,I}$.

When we don't use subscripts, we are being sloppy and assume the picture is understood from context.

Comment: Right. What I'd highlight is that the eigenfunctions of an operator are generally **complete** which means you can take **any** wavefunction $|\Psi\rangle$ and express it in terms of the basis functions $|\chi_i\rangle$ of a totally unrelated Hamiltonian $\hat h$ -- e.g. you can write particle-in-a-box states as a superposition of quantum harmonic oscillator states. The "interaction picture" for $\hat h$ is, as you say, just transforming into the Heisenberg coordinates for $\hat h$.

Comment: In the beginning, can we just split as well the Heisenberg picture? and have the same result?